# SQLite and C# - INSERT and UPDATE whit CASE check

Tags: c#, sqlite, insert

I'm trying to edit the insertions in this table, using C# and sqlite.

SQLite Table:

```
CREATE TABLE "utenti" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "grado" TEXT,
    "cognome"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "nome"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "codice_fiscale"    TEXT
)
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE "entrate" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "id_utente" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "nome"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "entrata"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "uscita"    TEXT
);
```

I would like to make sure that first we go to check if there is a record with the "id_utente" inserted in the textbox.
If it exists and the value of the "uscita" column is empty, update the row and add value in "uscita" column .
While if there are no lines with "id_utente" inserted in the textbox, or if they exist but "entrata" and "uscita" column value has been entered, insert a new record.

---

Test Code:

```
public static bool SavePerson(int idUtente, string nome, string orario)
        {
            using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
            {
                var output = cnn.Query($"select * from utenti where id = {idUtente}").FirstOrDefault();


                if (output != null) {
                    nome = FindCognome(idUtente);
                    string query;


                    query = $"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT (id_utente, nome, entrata) FROM entrate WHERE id_utente = '\"{idUtente}\"')" +
                    $"BEGIN" 
                    $"INSERT INTO entrate (id_utente, nome, entrata) VALUES (\"{idUtente}\",\"{nome}\",\"{orario}\")" +
                    $"END" +
                    $"ELSE" +
                    $"BEGIN" +
                    $"UPDATE entrate (id_utente, nome, entrata) VALUES (\"{idUtente}\",\"{nome}\",\"{orario}\") WHERE id_utente = '\"{idUtente}\"')" +
                    $"END";

                    //cnn.Execute($"INSERT INTO entrate (id_utente, nome, entrata) VALUES (\"{idUtente}\",\"{nome}\",\"{orario}\")");


                    cnn.Execute(query);
                    cnn.Close();
                    return true;
                } 
                else return false;

            }
        }
```

I have made various tests and various attempts but I find myself in difficulty, for the control variable of the row in the table.

---

OTHER WRONG TEST

```
query = $"UPDATE entrate SET uscita = \"{orario}\"," +
                        $"CASE WHEN id_utente = {idUtente}" +
                        $"ELSE INSERT INTO entrate (id_utente, nome, entrata) VALUES (\"{idUtente}\",\"{nome}\",\"{orario}\")";
```

Comment: If you are using SQLite then use the SQL syntax expected by SQLite. https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-exists/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by going to change some tables and how they are read

SQLite Table:

```
CREATE TABLE "utenti" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "grado" TEXT,
    "cognome"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "nome"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "codice_fiscale"    TEXT,
    "presente"  INTEGER
)
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE "entrate" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "id_utente" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "nome"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "entrata"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "uscita"    TEXT
)
```

---

Code:

```
public static bool SavePerson(int idUtente, string nome, string orario)
{
    using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
    {
        var output = cnn.Query($"select * from utenti where id = {idUtente}").FirstOrDefault();

        if (output != null) {
            nome = FindCognome(idUtente);
            var checkpresenza = cnn.QuerySingle<int>($"select presente from utenti where id = \"{idUtente}\" limit 1");
            Console.WriteLine(checkpresenza);

            if (checkpresenza == 0)
            {
                cnn.Execute($"INSERT INTO entrate (id_utente, nome, entrata) VALUES (\"{idUtente}\",\"{nome}\",\"{orario}\")");
                cnn.Execute($"UPDATE utenti SET presente = \"1\"  WHERE id = {idUtente}");
                presenza = 0;

            }
            else if (checkpresenza == 1)
            {
                cnn.Execute($"UPDATE entrate SET uscita = \"{orario}\" where id_utente = {idUtente}");
                cnn.Execute($"UPDATE utenti SET presente = \"0\"  WHERE id = {idUtente}");
                presenza = 1;
            }

            cnn.Close();
            return true;
        } 
        else return false;

        }

}
```